# Custom name for inserted input field JQuery

Tags: jquery

In my wordpress website i am inserting input field's and getting data with Ajax.

**This is Jquery:**

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.post-link', function() {
        $('#post-cont').fadeIn();
        var post_names = '';
        var ajax = {};
        ajax.id = $(this).attr('rel');
        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, {
            'action': 'get_img_post_and_title',
            'data': ajax
        }, function(response) {

            if (response.success) {

                if (post_names === '') {
                    post_names = 'aa';
                } else if (post_names === 'aa') {
                    post_names = 'ab';
                } else if (post_names === 'ab') {
                    post_names = 'ac';
                } else {
                    post_names = 'ad';
                }
                if ($('#post-cont input').length <= 4) {
                    $('#post-cont').append('<div class="rows"><input name="' + post_names + '" value="' + response.data.post_id + '"> ' + response.data.post_title + '   <img src="' + response.data.post_thumb + '"/></input></div>');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**PHP:**

```
 add_action("wp_ajax_get_img_post_and_title", "get_img_post_and_title");
 add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_get_img_post_and_title", "get_img_post_and_title");
    function get_img_post_and_title(){
     $return = array(    

    'post_id' => $_POST['data']['id'],
    'post_title' => get_the_title($_POST['data']['id']),
    'post_thumb' => wp_get_attachment_image_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($_POST['data']['id'])),           
    );      

    wp_send_json_success($return);    
   }
```

With this script i am trying to control the `max number of input field to 4` and assign then custom names from `aa, ab, ac, ad`.

And this script add max 4 successfully but assign only  `aa` name to all that is wrong.

**How to assign 4 different name's to all inserted fields?**

Comment: why don't you just assign the `response.data.post_id` as `name` as well?

Comment: @edi i need fixed name, just because i am getting data from input field on other page. As in html form

Comment: oh of course I see. Maybe use a global var `var input_count = 0;` and set `post_names = 'a' + (++input_count);`. Sorry I'm just not a fan of that if-block ;)

Comment: @edi that will be appreciated, please post answer in your way. i just need 4 input with there name. for a Form to get them on other page

Comment: @edi Something like that on data.php  `<?php if (isset ( $_POST['aa'] )){ $ID = $_POST['aa'] ; echo get_post_meta( $ID, 'brand', true ); } ?>`

Comment: ok, let me think ... ;)

Comment: wait one more question: what is the reason you are using an input field here? What type of input should it actually be - hidden, text, button, submit?

Comment: sorry to flood ... but if I understand right you'd like to add a link or a button when ajax request is received and when the user is clicking on one of them that one should be processed in `data.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following code snap:

```
<script>
var custom_input_names = ['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad'];

$(function() {

    $('body').on('click', '.post-link', function() {
        $('#post-cont').fadeIn();
        var post_names = '';
        var ajax = {};
        ajax.id = $(this).attr('rel');
        var ajaxurl = '<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
        jQuery.post(ajaxurl, {
            'action': 'get_img_post_and_title',
            'data': ajax
        }, function(response) {

            if (response.success) {

                for (var i=0; i<custom_input_names.length; i++) {
                    if ($('#post-cont').find('input[name=' + custom_input_names[i] + ']').length < 1) {
                      $('#post-cont').append('<div class="rows"><input name="' + custom_input_names[i] + '" value="' + response.data.post_id + '"> ' + response.data.post_title + '   <img src="' + response.data.post_thumb + '"/></input></div>');
                      break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

You can add more elements to `custom_input_names` if you want the limit more than 4.
For example, if you want maximum 7, then you can change `custom_input_names` like following:

```
var custom_input_names = ['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'af', 'ag'];
```

Comment: Simply you are awesome in coding. Thanks a alot

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code that prevents the `post_names` status of updating to the last used input field name. Remove the `1` and it should work! (your variable is called `post_names1` in one of the lines of code!) ;-)

```
if (post_names === '') {
  post_names = 'aa';
} else if (post_names**l** === 'aa'){
  post_names = 'ab';
} else if (post_names === 'ab'){
  post_names = 'ac';
} else {
  post_names = 'ad';
}
```

Fixed (also changed the last one that sets it to `ad` a little, just to be sure):

```
if (post_names === '') {
  post_names = 'aa';
} else if (post_names === 'aa'){
  post_names = 'ab';
} else if (post_names === 'ab'){
  post_names = 'ac';
} else if (post_names === 'ac'){
  post_names = 'ad';
}
```

Other than that, you're resetting the state of `post_names` every time this function runs. You should move `post_names = ''` out of the function.

```
var post_names = '';
if (response.success) {
    if (post_names === '') {
        post_names = 'aa';
    } else if (post_names === 'aa') {
        post_names = 'ab';
    } else if (post_names === 'ab') {
        post_names = 'ac';
    } else {
        post_names = 'ad';
    }
    if ($('#post-cont input').length <= 4) {
        $('#post-cont').append('<div class="rows"><input name="' + post_names + '" value="' + response.data.post_id + '"> ' + response.data.post_title + '   <img src="' + response.data.post_thumb + '"/></input></div>');
    }
}
```

Comment: This would prevent the script from adding the elements because of a `ReferenceError` (if there isn't a global `post_names1` anywhere in the script). But FRQ wrote: _"And this script add max 4 successfully"_.

Comment: (post_names**l** === 'aa') is just a mistake. problem not solve

Comment: Now, You have copied mine. that to without removing the obvious

Comment: @Satpal you're not the only one to spot the reference error ;-) The typo was the first thing I noticed (within a few seconds of reading OP's question). When he changed/corrected his question, I had another look and spotted the error of him resetting the variable's state to empty on every execution of this function and corrected it for him. I see someone else suggested this too but chose for a `let` scope in stead of a `var` scope, which doesn't seem appropriate here.

Comment: Wow :) Then should have posted it before having an argument  (with me) after going through my answer and Sebastián answer. Reread your statement_No need to add it to your answer if I already spotted and posted it below though._

Comment: No need to be sad pal. I just did what you did to show you that it's a douche move. If you had just said something like "also note the typo that LaurensSwart noticed", all would have been good ;-)

Comment: Now be happy. I removed my answer. Atleast fix you answer and fix the incorrect portion related to TYPO. And just for record, I reached answer independently(so no need to give attribution). As I have seen enough typos at SO thus it was just a footnote

Comment: And I reached my fix independently too upon taking a second look when OP updated his question, so I don't really see the problem :)

Comment: Really I don't think so.

Comment: @LaurensSwart This code not solve the problem. please check here Ajax also using.

Answer (score 0):

What would be nice ...

- assign input type to `<input>`
- use a form for each row instead of one
- place the id inside a hidden field with name id
- do not place images inside of an input (better: example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2pbtB/573/))

The long answer ... ;)

```
if (response.success) {
  $form = '<div class="rows">' +
          '<form method="POST" action="data.php">' +
          '  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' + response.data.post_id + '">' +
          '  <div class="input_container">' +
          '    <input type="submit" class="myinput" value="' + response.data.post_title + '">' +
          '    <img src="' + response.data.post_thumb + '" id="input_img">' +
          '  </div>' +
          '</form>' +
          '</div>';

  $('#post-cont').append($form);
}
```

css part:

```
.input_container {
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.myinput {
    height:20px;
    margin:0;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
.input_container img {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:8px;
    left:10px;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
}
```

in data.php

```
$ID = $_POST['id'];
echo get_post_meta( $ID, 'brand', true );
```

Comment: I submit all 3 or 4 input field with submit button.